# How do I execute this complicated Pandas merge of two dataframes? Best described through an example, detailed example included

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

Here are two datataframes that I'd like to merge together, along with the resulting data frame.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Show':['NBA Basketball','NHL Hockey'],'Start_Time':['19:00','15:00'],'End_Time':['20:00','15:30']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Show':['NBA Basketball','NBA Basketball','NBA Basketball','NBA Basketball','NBA_Basketball','NHL Hockey','NHL Hockey','NHL Hockey'],'Half_Hour_Interval_Start':['19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:00','15:00','15:30','16:00'],'Viewers':[1000,2000,1500,1000,3000,2000,4000,5000]})


result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Show':['NBA Basketball','NHL Hockey'],'Start_Time':['19:00','15:00'],'End_Time':['20:00','15:30'],'Viewers':[3000,2000]})
```

[image]

I want to essentially compute the sum of viewers in df2 only where the half hour interval is between the start time and end time of df1. Bit of a complicated merge here. Notice how in the result_df, the viewers column is only a subset of the total viewers from df2, depending on the official start time and end time of the show in df1.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a complicated merge, try a general merge, followed by grouped summing on a condition.

First, a general merge. Since we want it to merge on 'Show' (the only column in common), there's no need to specify a merge on column.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)

print(df3)

             Show Start_Time End_Time Half_Hour_Interval_Start  Viewers
0  NBA Basketball      19:00    20:00                    19:00     1000
1  NBA Basketball      19:00    20:00                    19:30     2000
2  NBA Basketball      19:00    20:00                    20:00     1500
3  NBA Basketball      19:00    20:00                    20:30     1000
4      NHL Hockey      15:00    15:30                    15:00     2000
5      NHL Hockey      15:00    15:30                    15:30     4000
6      NHL Hockey      15:00    15:30                    16:00     5000
```

Then on your condition, groupby 'Show' then sum.

```
df3[df3['Half_Hour_Interval_Start'].between(df3['Start_Time'], df3['End_Time'], inclusive='left')].groupby(['Show', 'Start_Time', 'End_Time'])[['Viewers']].sum().reset_index()

                 Show Start_Time End_Time  Viewers
0  NBA Basketball      19:00    20:00     3000
1      NHL Hockey      15:00    15:30     2000
```